# How I fix "Couldn't find a distribution for 'ploneconf.site'" in Mastering Plone Training

Tags: python, plone, plone-4.x

I'm learning create custom products for plone (4.3.10) using Mastering Plone, and I stop in the [section](https://training.plone.org/4/eggs1.html#including-the-egg-in-plone) when I install the newly package created with mrbob.

[Here](http://paster.org/m/bkfydi/) is my buildout (I uncomment the lines informed by trainnig)

And my directory:

```
jafar@plonedev:~/training/buildout$ pwd
/home/jafar/training/buildout

jafar@plonedev:~/training/buildout$ ls -l src
drwxrwxr-x 4 jafar jafar 4096 Ago 22 16:15 ploneconf.site
drwxrwxr-x 4 jafar jafar 4096 Ago 22 15:13 ploneconf.site_sneak
```

**[UPDATE]**

I did all again in training, and the buildout is http://paster.org/m/lnpaxn, Icreated the package usind this command:

```
$ cd src
$ ../bin/mrbob -O ploneconf.site bobtemplates:plone_addon
```

After answering the questions it ... I ran the buildout, and this is my output:

```
(py27) jafar@plonedev:~/training/buildout/src$ ls
ploneconf.site  ploneconf.site_sneak
(py27) jafar@plonedev:~/training/buildout/src$ cd ..
(py27) jafar@plonedev:~/training/buildout$ vim buildout.cfg
(py27) jafar@plonedev:~/training/buildout$ ./bin/buildout
mr.developer: Queued 'ploneconf.site_sneak' for checkout.
mr.developer: Updated 'ploneconf.site_sneak' with git.
Upgraded:
  setuptools version 20.1.1;
restarting.
Generated script '/home/jafar/training/buildout/bin/buildout'.
mr.developer: Queued 'ploneconf.site_sneak' for checkout.
mr.developer: Updated 'ploneconf.site_sneak' with git.
Uninstalling zopepy.
Uninstalling packages.
Running uninstall recipe.
Uninstalling instance.
Uninstalling codeintel.
Updating _mr.developer.
Updating checkversions.
Installing codeintel.
Couldn't find index page for 'ploneconf.site' (maybe misspelled?)
Getting distribution for 'ploneconf.site'.
Couldn't find index page for 'ploneconf.site' (maybe misspelled?)
While:
  Installing codeintel.
  Getting distribution for 'ploneconf.site'.
Error: Couldn't find a distribution for 'ploneconf.site'.
```

Just remembering...

I'm follow this training:
https://training.plone.org/4/eggs1.html#including-the-egg-in-plone

**[UPDATE 2]**

I think the problem is in buildout.cfg, in section SOURCE we have this

```
[sources]
ploneconf.site = fs ploneconf.site full-path=${buildout:directory}/src/ploneconf.site
```

I tried replace ${buildout:directory} to full path

```
/home/jafar/training/buildout/src/ploneconf.site
```

And yet, it didn't work!

The content of product generated by mrbob

```
jafar@plonedev:~/training/buildout/src/ploneconf.site$ ls
bootstrap-buildout.py   bootstrap-buildout.pyo  CHANGES.rst       docs         README.rst  setup.py  travis.cfg
bootstrap-buildout.pyc  buildout.cfg            CONTRIBUTORS.rst  MANIFEST.in  setup.cfg   src
```

Comment: you seem to be using Plone 5.0.5 rather than Plone 4.3.10 according to your buildout, if you don't have a strong reason for, use that one (Plone 5)

Comment: how did you get the ploneconf.site and ploneconf.site_sneak into your src folder? Did you run buildout and they were downloaded automatically?

Comment: I clone the git repository, brach plone4, and I trusted in buildout... I'll change the version and see what happen... the results I'll post here...

Comment: @gforcada, about (1) ploneconf.site and (2) ploneconf.site_sneak. (1) I created it using mrbob, and (2) appear when I run for first time the `bin/buildout -v`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I insert in [buildout] section after eggs and zcml this:

```
develop =
    src/ploneconf.site
```

As seen in [Plone Docs](http://docs.plone.org/4/en/old-reference-manuals/buildout/creatingpackage.html), the way teaching in training [Mastering Plone 4](https://training.plone.org/4/eggs1.html#including-the-egg-in-plone) didn't work.